# Why do I get a "Level too low" message when trying to Techcopy?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I am up against Basik, he is level 31.  Wakka is level 30... When trying to learn, it says "Wakkas level is too low." It says that when I Techcopy, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting a "Level too low" indicator when attempting to copy a technique, this means that the character you're trying to copy from is a higher level than the character you're playing as. It is still possible to Techcopy as a lower level player, but the chance of success is reduced because of it.

In your case, Basik is level 31 while Wakka is level 30 so Techcopying will be more difficult than if Wakka tried to Techcopy at an equal or higher level than Basik.

Comment: Alright, by low level difference I thought it meant a level 15 trying to learn from a level 30. I didn't know it meant even a 1 level difference. Thank you for clarifying.